# import qualified in GHCI

Tags: haskell, ghci

Does it is possible to use the equivalent of "import qualified" in GHCI with our OWN module? Something like `:m + qualified Data.List` which of course doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

Just type `import qualified Data.Text` or `import qualified Data.Text as T` inside ghci, just as you would do inside your code.

Comment: Note that this was added in GHC 7.0.

Comment: Hum sorry, I meant my OWN module.

Comment: @vildric What makes you think your own module is any different than someone else's module?  Just `import qualified My.Own.Modules as MOM`, assuming a package with the `My.Own.Module` module is installed or the module is in scope via other means.

Comment: @vildric For your own module, given a file called `MyModule.hs` in working directory, with `module MyModule where` at the top. Just type `import qualified MyModule` and you're done.

Answer (score 16):

I don't know of a pretty way to do what you want, but you could fake it with something like this:

1. First, use `:load My/Module.hs` to load your module.
2. Use `:module - My.Module` to bring it out of scope.
3. (Optional.)  Use `import qualified My.Module as MM` to bring it into scope qualified.

Every module that GHCi knows about is automatically available fully qualified, so after step 2, `My.Module.value` will work fine.  Step 3 is only necessary if you want to use a shorter prefix.

If you want to load multiple files at once, `:load` can do that too;

```
:load My/Module1.hs My/Module2.hs ... My/ModuleN.hs
```

will work fine.  It will put you in the scope of `*My.Module1`, and then `My.Module2` … `My.ModuleN` will all be available fully qualified as mentioned above.

For more about GHCi, you can always check [the GHC User's Guide, Ch. 2: "Using GHCi"](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/ghci.html); particularly relevant sections are [§2.2, "Loading source files"](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/loading-source-files.html) and [§2.4.5, "What's really in scope at the prompt?"](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-scope).